# .net core 2.0 MVC - Views - how to access another models property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a simple MVC app. I have two models at the moment, Member, and MembershipType.

[image]

As you can see from my screenshot, my index view of Member model displays all the members (of the gym). The MembershipTypeId is a Foreign key linking to the MembershipType table / model.

In my MembershipType model, I have another property which stores the user friendly string of these numeric values. I want to display that on my Members view, instead of numeric values.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
        </td>
        <td>
            **@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MembershipTypeId)**
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

}

I could do a case statement within my Members view and hard code the human friendly string values, but there must be another way.

Apologies if this is simple, I am a beginner.

Thanks in advance

N.B I have selected the line in code I'm trying to amend,

Comment: The problem you have found will grow bigger and bigger. That is why we usually use __ViewModels__ in MVC. A separate class containing exactly what should be on the screen. The controller composes a ViewModel from one or more Models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model the MembershipType as a navigation property in your Member 
 Entity. This way, it can be lazy loaded when required.

```
public class Member {

   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   // foreign key for MembershipType 
   [ForeignKey("MembershipType")]
   public long MembershipTypeId { get; set; }

   public virtual MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can access the properties of MembershipType like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Member>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MembershipType.Name)
}
```

Comment: Hi Georg, 

Adding public virtual Membership {get;set;} in my Member model class throws up errors - The name get/set does not exist in current context.

Comment: There's an enumerator missing that's why you're getting the error. Just replace `public virtual MembershipType { get; set; }` with `public virtual MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }` where `MembershipType` is the enumerator containing the membership types.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the missing property name in the code example (as Intrepid suggested).